# Hide price in Bigcartel?

Tags: bigcartel

I'm trying to hide the price of certain products on my bigcartel site, as well at the "coming soon" text.  I'm using the Sidecar theme. I tried using code someone posted here several years ago for this, but nothing has worked.  Can anyone help me?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`unless` to the rescue !

Create an `[145758, 9675466, 6872210]` array with product Ids that not to show price and comming soon.

you can find product id by `product.id`

```
{% assign productIds = "145758,9675466,6872210" | split: ',' %}
```

`unless` print only if constrain is not met.

This prints nothing:

```
{% unless input contains '145758' %} Your comming or price HTML code block here {% endunless %}
```

This prints "Your block html code":

```
{% unless input contains '444444' %} Your comming or price HTML code block here{% endunless %}
```

Click to need [more help](https://www.fiverr.com/wetechteam/design-and-develop-eye-catchy-big-cartel-store-to-boost-sell)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the easiest way to hide both of these:

```css
div.product-price { display: none; }
div.status-text { display: none; }
```

Go to Design > Code > Custom CSS

Unfortunately, on some themes a boxed background for coming soon / sold out stays.